# Invalid floating point operation Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a problem in a Delphi program that i'm writing. The problem is this piece of code:

```
type
  TRobot = class(TObject)
  private
  public
    fAcceso: Boolean;
    fOra: TTime;
    fCode: Integer;
    mex: string;
    constructor Create;
  end;

// ...

myrobot.mex:= ('Acceso: '+  BoolToStr(myrobot.fAcceso) + 
               ',Tempo:' +  TimeToStr(myrobot.fOra) + 
               ',Codice:' + IntToStr(myrobot.fCode));  
memo.Lines.add(myrobot.mex);
```

precisely with `TimeToStr(myrobot.fOra)`.
The problem occurs is

> "Invalid floating point operation".

Can someone help me??

Comment: You are not giving the definition of myrobot, and in particular myrobot.fOra. Without that we can only guess. But my guess would be that for a is not of type TDateTime or TTime.

Comment: This is a function which you supply an argument to. If you call this same function in a test program with, for instance the value given by `Now`, then you will find that there is no problem. Therefore, it should be obvious to you that the issue lies in the value that you pass to the function. With that knowledge you know what to do next. Inspect the value of `myrobot.fOra`.

Comment: TRobot = class (TObject)
  private

  public
    fAcceso: Boolean;
    fOra: TTime;
    fCode: Integer;
    mex: string;
    constructor Create; myrobot is an object of type TRobot simply

Comment: None of that is relevant. What is the value of `myrobot.fOra`? Surely you can see that the value of a function's argument matters? It looks like you don't know how to debug. It's time to learn.

Comment: Luca, I added the class to your question. You can edit your own posts with the "edit" button below the tags.

Comment: Is `myrobot` properly initialized with something like `myrobot := TRobot.Create;`? If not, all the fields are rubbish, and can very well be a NaN or an invalid TTime, which could cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means division by zero, square root of negative value and similar issues. It looks like something wrong either with myrobot.fOra or with format settings.

Set breakpoint at this line and check fOra value. If it looks good, use F7 to step into TimeToStr (yes, you can debug system library routines... maybe you'll need to install VCL sources and/or set up 'use debug dcu(s)' option of your project). Using it you'll be able to reach exact place of error and check what's wrong.

Comment: There won't be any need to debug VCL sources. The problem will be obvious as soon as the asker inspects the value. The asker just doesn't yet know how to debug, how to inspect intermediate values during the execution of the program.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Before answering I spent some time trying to reproduce this exception and failed. Any value I tried was successfully TimeToStr-ed, so, maybe, error is not so simple.

Comment: It's really simply. Try passing a NaN, of Inf, or even 1e300